# Constructing a lambda expression using an underscore

Tags: scala, lambda, anonymous-function

This code

```
(1 to 30).foreach { x =>
  println(x)
  println
}
```

does what I'd expect: it prints each of `1` to `30`, interspersed with blanks. I'm pretty clear on what's going on here, I think: I'm passing an anonymous function that first prints its argument, and then prints a blank line.

What I don't understand is why this doesn't do the same:

```
(1 to 30).foreach {
  println _
  println
}
```

It looks equivalent to me. The underscore should represent the first and only argument to the function; and the function prints its argument, and then prints a blank line. But when I run this second version, I don't get the blank lines.

What causes this difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first variant is straightforward:

1. In the first line, apply `println` on `x`.
2. In the second line, apply the no-argument `println` (**this prints the extra newline**).

With the second variant you effectively tell Scala to do this:

1. In the first line, define a function object from `println()`.
   Subsequently, do nothing with this newly created object.
2. In the second line, apply `println` to the argument (the element of the
   sequence).

The confusion stems from the assumption that `println(x)` and `println _` are equivalent. **They are different.** The `funcId _` syntax defines a new function based on `funcId`, it is not the same as using the "underscore argument" notation when calling a function.

Answer (score 6):

There is a number of things going on here.

First, of all the parameter placeholder syntax can only be used within outer parentheses of the lambda definition. It cannot be used within parentheses of the method calls that you perform within the lambda definition.

Here is an example to demonstrate this point.

```
val a = (1 to 10).map(_ + 1)
```

This will work.

```
val b = (1 to 10).map(math.sin(_ + 1))
```

This will not work.

Therefore your code does not use parameter placeholder syntax at all. It instead uses partially applied functions.

For example

```
(1 to 10).foreach(println _)
```

is functionally equal to

```
val a = println (_ : Int)
(1 to 10).foreach(a)
```

Also when a method name is used within lambda expression the underscore can be omitted. Scala will still generate the partially applied method.

Therefore

```
(1 to 10).foreach(println)
```

is equal to

```
(1 to 10).foreach(println _)
```

And therefore your code is equal to

```
val a = println (_ : Int)
  (1 to 10).foreach{
    a
    a
  }
```

And because {a a} returns a, it is equal to

```
val a = println (_ : Int)
(1 to 10).foreach(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to other answers, there actually exists a way to use `println(_)` and not to declare `x` parameter:

```
(1 to 30).foreach {
  println(_: Int)
  println
}
```

Here `foreach` parameter is function, which firstly invokes `println(_)` for range element, and then passes `println(Int)` result (which is `(): Unit`) to another function, `_ => println`, which ignores it's argument and prints new line.